# Reading a file for a certain number of characters

Tags: java, file-io

I have a file that i need to read a certain number of characters into a string. how can i do this in java?

Comment: How about reading something first? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/file.html

Comment: nothing idk how im supposed to open the file to read it correctly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the normal `while` loop to read the file but add a counter and use it as a second stop criteria.

---

```
public String readFirstChars(File f, int number) throws IOException {
  Reader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
          new FileInputStream(f), "US-ASCII"));
  try {
    StringBuilder resultBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    int count = 0;
    int intch;
    while (((intch = r.read()) != -1) && count < number) {
      resultBuilder.append((char) intch);
      count++;
    }
    return resultBuilder.toString();
  } finally {
    r.close();
  }
}
```

(replace the encoding String with the one that you need, "UTF-8" maybe)

Comment: i was more looking for a method to do it.

Comment: There is no one-liner to do this in Java. Well, not if you format the code properly ;-)

Comment: @DNA - **every** java class can be written in a single line ;-)

Comment: public class OneLiner{public static void main(String[] args){System.out.println("This is evil!");}}

Comment: `public class MyOneLiner{public static void main(String[] args){OneLiner.main(args);}}`